# Regular Expressions: Positive Lookahead and Word Border question

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Hello again Stackoverflow people!

Assume I have these words: smartphones, smartphone

I want to match the substring "phone" from within them. However, in both case, I want only "phone" to be returned, not "phones" in the first case. In addition to this, I want matches only if the word "phone" is a suffix only, such that:

fonephonetics (just an example) is not matched.

I assumed that the regex

```
(phone([?=s])?)\b
```

would give me what I need, but it is currently matching "phones" and "phone", but not the "fonephonetics" one. I don't need "phones". I want "phone" for both cases.

Any ideas about what is wrong, and what I can do?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you know what substring you're looking for, why do you need the regex to return that substring?

Comment: What language are you using? [?=s] usually means a character class that matches any of `?`, `=` or `s`.

Comment: @Mark: Java.

@mmyers: Because I need to see if "phone" occurs within a series of lines, and if so, return the lines that contain it. But I also want variations of phone for eg. "phones" to be matched.

This is a much simplified example btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To match `phone` followed by either `s\b` or `\b`:

```
phone(?=s?\b)
```

The lookahead is a zero-width match so the `s` won't be returned as part of the match.

Comment: Your solution works. What if I have to use alternation to match a series of other words as suffixes?(phone(?=s?\b)|test|test2)\b won't work then.

Any solutions?

Comment: @Inf: Isolate the alternation in its own set of parentheses: `(phone|test|test2)(?=s?\b)`

Comment: Many thanks! That is what I wanted! :)

Could you please tell me why, when putting the (?=s?\b) in its own parenthesis, it works? Or point me to some link where I can get that info?

Comment: Inf.S: It's a zero-width lookahead meaning that it matches 0 characters. You can read more about it here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html